# How to make Chrome window size as wide as window resolution

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, window, screen-resolution

I have my monitor with resolution 2560 x 1440, however I don't know why my chrome browser has only 1754px width in full screen. I checked the zoom of chrome is 100%. I checked other browsers, they all have 2560 width in full screen. And I also reinstalled chrome, but the problem still there. Are there any potential problem there that I can fix it back? Thanks for answering!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just tested myself, the problem is the font-size setting in my Windows OS:
Setting -> Display -> Make text bigger. It it value is more than 100%, then Chrome browser will shrink it's width. Double checked: there is no width shirking on Firefox and IE, but Chrome and Edge under the mentioned setting.